# <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)" when using Interactive Guideline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am currently working with NVD3 using Angular Directive (angular-nvd3). I have a very simple line chart with very simple data.

**Everything is working fine, at the beginning.
However if you decide to turn off (disable) one set of data the error rises:**

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"
```

**I replicated the problem with a plunker:** 
http://plnkr.co/edit/e4D619?p=preview

*Disable any set to see the error in console. Resize the window and disable/enable the set to see the error again. Turn off useInteractiveGuideline to eliminate the errors.*

Still, I do not know if it is a bug with nvd3 or d3 or with the dataset somehow. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a bad interaction between what is rendered via nvd3 and some d3 animation code.  Might want to raise an issue with the nvd3 team: https://github.com/novus/nvd3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was reported and is already solved in master:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1373#event-475991935